# Merge static analyzer reports

Tags: static-analysis, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd, sonarlint

I want to merge the reports generated by PMD, FindBugs, and SonarLint to give the user a more general preview by combining the important warnings reported by each of them. So can someone suggest to me as how can these individual reports can be merged?

Answer (score 0):

We use [warmings-ng](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/) plugin for Jenkins, it can aggregate multiple reports from different static analyzers.
It can be used in Jenkins pipeline like this (it aggregates warnings from maven build output, java compiler and checkstyle)

```
recordIssues aggregatingResults: true, tools: [checkStyle(), mavenConsole(), java()]
```

Full list of supported tools you can check [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/SUPPORTED-FORMATS.md) (all analyzers you mentioned are supported)